# Who was Kāśyapa?

Tags: mahabharata

In beginning chapters of Mahabharata:Adi Parva it's stated that Kāśyapa (काश्यप) was going to King Parikshit on the day when Taksaka was supposed to kill him. But Taksaka met with him on the way and returned him after giving lot of money (which he wished to get from the king Parikshit after saving his life).

> तं ददर्श स नागेन्द्रस्तक्षकः **काश्यपं** पथि।
>
> गच्छन्तमेकमनसं द्विजो भूत्वा वयोऽतिगः॥ 1-42-37 ~[Sanskrit Shlokas source](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-01-sa.html)

My question is who was this Kāśyapa (काश्यप)? Was he related to famous sage Kaśyapa (कश्यप)? [This link](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kashyapa) gives some info but not conclusive enough.

Also if he was someone other than Kaśyapa (कश्यप) then,  what was the significance of Lord Brahma teaching Vishharini vidya to Kaśyapa when Kadru cursed her children Sarpas/Nagas?

> आहूय **कश्यपं** देव इदं वचनमब्रवीत्।
>
> यदेते दन्दशूकाश्च सर्पा जातास्त्वयानघ॥ 1-20-14 ~[Sanskrit Shlokas source](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-01-sa.html)

Comment: "Kāśyapa (काश्यप)" is a generic name indicative of the lineage of Kaśyapa (कश्यप). There is one of the latter and many of the former.

Answer (score 1):

There was another sage Kasyapa born from Sage Marichi.

> **Marichi had one son called Kasyapa**. This last also has two names. Some call
> him Arishtanemi, and some Kasyapa.

> **Shanti Parva CCVIII**

Comment: But the Kashyapa in Astika parva is not sage Kashyapa.

Comment: Is this the same Ariṣṭanēmi invoked in the Śāntimantra 'bhadraṃ karṇēbhiḥ śṛṇyāmadēvāḥ...'

Answer (score 0):

1. [Kadru curses all 1000 sons/snakes](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01021.htm), for their refusing to make the tail of  the horse Uchchaihsravas look black, to get consumed in the the snake-sacrifice of the wise king Janamejaya of the Pandava race.  Later Brahma consoles  Kāśyapa, the father of snakes, and teaches him ***the knowledge of neutralising poison***.
2. Takshaka meets Kāśyapa, who was on his way to meet the King Parikshit to save him.   [Takshaka proposed to give gold](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01044.htm) to Kāśyapa, 3 times what the latter was expecting from king Parikshit.  Kāśyapa accepts that gold and returns.

According to Mahabharata, it was the same Kāśyapa (काश्यप), who was the father of snakes and who also tried to rescue King Parikshit.

However, it is not clear as to how both Takshaka and Kāśyapa could not recognise each other.

Comment: they were different as per Sanskrit Shloka..In english aa and a is mostly written as a..Like both Shivā and Shiva are written as Shiva but they are actually different..

Comment: @YDS: You are right partially,  This [link](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/kashyapa) says, it is difficult to differentiate them.